# Subtracting row values of a same column

Tags: sql

im kind of new to SQL .I wanted to know if there is an efficient way of subtracting row values of a same column.The column looks like this -

Credit_Entry

```
 21000
 71800
 117300
 118200
```

So what I want is row2-row1,row3-row2,row4-row3 and store the result in a seperate column.

Comment: SQL tables represent unordered sets.  There is no "next" or "prev" row, unless another column indicates the ordering.  Do you have such a column?  Also, tag your question with the actual database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an `id` column or something similar, then the easiest way is to use the ANSI standard function `lag()`:

```
select t.*, t.value - lag(value) over (order by id) as diff
from table t;
```

Many, but not all, databases support this functionality.